# Any place other then pyyaml.org to get pyyaml?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pyyaml.org seems to be down and thus the easy_install step ("sudo easy_install -U pyyaml") is failing for me.

Any ideas on how else I can move forward with my Diamondback os x install?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10751/any-place-other-then-pyyaml.org-to-get-pyyaml?/) by [Paul Mans](https://answers.ros.org/users/904/paul-mans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Macports has pyyaml (py26-yaml). Don't know if rosdep will have an issue with using the macports version though.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul Mans](https://answers.ros.org/users/904/paul-mans/) on 2011-07-27**:
I ended up reinstalling rosinstall with the following command so that rosinstall was no longer located at /usr/local/bin/rosinstall and this in conjunction with py26-yaml from ports fixed it.    sudo /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/easy_install-2.6 -U rosinstall

**Comment by [Paul Mans](https://answers.ros.org/users/904/paul-mans/) on 2011-07-27**:
Got py26-yaml via macports however I still have the problem "ImportError:  No module named yaml".  Appending the following to PYTHONPATH doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml

**Comment by [Paul Mans](https://answers.ros.org/users/904/paul-mans/) on 2011-07-27**:
Thanks, I'll give it a try!